# hide/show keyboard on titanium

Tags: android, ios, titanium

I have a problem with `titanium sdk` that i want to show the keyboard when i click on the `textField` and i want it to hide when i click outside that `textField`

i tried `textField.blur()`

```
view.addEventListener("click", function(e){
if(Ti.Platform.name === 'iPhone OS')
textbox.blur();  
});
```

but it works on iphone but on android the keyboard didn't launch any more

i also tried `TI.UI.Android.hidesoftkey`

but i got same result on android

any help ?

Answer (score 0):

to hide and show key board, we normally use .blur() and .focus() method for both platform so you should remove platform specific condition in view's click event.

```
view.addEventListener("click", function(e){
textbox.blur();  
});
```

Comment: your solution works on iphone but on android the keyboard doesn't luanch